React-Select compressed and not completely unwound
I have a problem with a React select component,
It doesn't unwind completely, the drop-down menu only displays part of the options and
I have a scroll bar on the right to scroll through the rest of the options.
I don't want this scroll bar, I'd like my menu, to be displayed in its entirety, not cropped.
I don't have any style, I've uninstalled reinstalled react-select, restarted my PC, Visual Studio Code etc....
I tried with and without the strict mode
Another persons with the exact same code doesn't have this problem.
[My program](https://i.sstatic.net/opn1rSA4.png)
[How it is used](https://i.sstatic.net/fMqPA46t.png)

[Select non-clicked](https://i.sstatic.net/GsFvsYPQ.png)
[Select clicked](https://i.sstatic.net/YFM5FAox.png)
[Select when I scrolled](https://i.sstatic.net/MxYgtbpB.png)

Thanks in advance.

I tried to have a successfully working react-select with a full drop-down menu and not a scroll bar

You certainly have a overflow-x somewhere in your style.
Just remove it and it will work.
